# Change Column name in a repeater asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, bootstrap-4, repeater

Good morning everyone!

I'm making a repeater with days (monday, thuesday...) in columns, i need to change these columns names for the actual day name and actual number.

Something like this:

- Selecting day from a week:

[image: Calendar]

- Then if i select 25/02/2018, then i need to show Lunes 26/02, Martes 27/02 ... Viernes 02/03:

[image: Repeater]

The "Semana - Week" textbox returns a DateTime. The repeater binds on click "Buscar - Find" button.

The question is:

¿How i can change the column name on every bind to get the result i want?

Thanks all!

Comment: I don't get it. In a Repeater you create the columns yourself (unlike a GridView). So you can just change the colum names in the HTML.

Comment: I have a repeater table, with colums that i need to create names dinamically, i have a callendar complement added, i need to do:

(Look the calendar image)
If i select for example monday 5, i need the columns name:
Time, Monday 5, Thuesday 6, Wedneday 7, Thursday 8, Friday 9
If i select for example wednesday 14, i need the columns name:
Time, Monday 12, Thuesday 13, Wednesday 14, Thursday 15, Friday 16.

I need to do this with every week and month of the year. The question is ¿How to put that day number in the column name, how to change from code behind?

Comment: Why not use a GridView? It has columns and rows.

Comment: only because this is a repeater exercise :( i need to do this with a repeater, ¿there is a way to change the <th></th> names and include the number on it?

Comment: You can use something like this `<th><%# Eval("ColumnName") %></th>` inside a Repeater

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem using labels in th:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Horario</th>
    <th><asp:Label ID="lbllunes" runat="server" Text="Lunes"></asp:Label></th>
    <th><asp:Label ID="lblmartes" runat="server" Text="Martes"></asp:Label></th>
    <th><asp:Label ID="lblmiercoles" runat="server" Text="Miercoles"></asp:Label></th>
    <th><asp:Label ID="lbljueves" runat="server" Text="Jueves"></asp:Label></th>
    <th><asp:Label ID="lblviernes" runat="server" Text="Viernes"></asp:Label></th>
</tr></thead>
```

Then i can handle this labels on _ItemCreated() of repeater this way:

```
Label labellunes = e.Item.FindControl("lbllunes") as Label;
Label labelmartes = e.Item.FindControl("lblmartes") as Label;
Label labelmiercoles = e.Item.FindControl("lblmiercoles") as Label;
Label labeljueves = e.Item.FindControl("lbljueves") as Label;
Label labelviernes = e.Item.FindControl("lblviernes") as Label;
```

Dont know if is better solution but this works for me!!